# Grails find domain objects with many to many relationship, with a list as parameter

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria, grails-2.0

I have a simple class Song, to which I can attribute some tags :

```
class Song {
    String title
    static hasMany = [tags:Tag]
}
```

Then, i would like to be able to find all songs having a given list of tags, for example this would look like :

```
List<Song> results = Song.findAll("where tags contains ?", [myTagList]);
```

For example, if I have :

```
a Song S1 with tags T1
a Song S2 with tags T1 T2 T3
a Song S3 with tags T1 T3
a Song S4 with tags T1 T2 T3 T4
```

And I execute my query with `myTagList containing T1, T2, T3`, then the call will return `S2 and S4`.

Is there any efficient way to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use criteria with an "in" query:

```
Song.createCriteria().list{
    "in"("tags",myTagList)
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is the complexity of this call ? If for example I have thousands of songs in base, i would like to avoid calls that grab the whole list of songs and then iterate on them to find matchings.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, i've been trying to do some more research, but this should return to you a list of Songs where the tag is matched, using an sql in statement which doesn't use any grails iteration.

Comment: Have you tried your solution ? Maybe I did something wrong but I tried on my side and it apparently doesn't work. What is expected is a simple class attribute (which should not be a list) as first parameter, and a list in which we want to find the attribute. In my case, it is quite the opposite (i want "tags" to contain myTagList), with lists in both parameters.
Example from Grails documentation : 'in'("age",[18..65])

Comment: My apologies, i think i misunderstood what you are after, it sounds like you want to compare a list of columns (tags) to a list of values, is that correct? I don't know of a simple way to do this, sorry.

Comment: Yes, what i am basically looking for, is the list of songs that have all tags of a given list. I update my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

What about a dynamic finder?

```
List<Song> results = Song.findAllByTagsInList(myTagList);
```

Comment: It works for simple arguments, like Song.findAllByTitleInList(["title1","title2"]), but when I call it with findAllByTagsInList, it crashes with : "Class: java.sql.SQLException, Message: No value specified for parameter 1"